# Android facebook send app request to friend

Tags: android, facebook

I am able to fetch the facebook friends list.Now I am trying to send app request to one of my selected facebook friend.I am getting success dialog at my end but it's not reflecting on my friends account.

Here is my code to send app request:

```
//SEND FRIEND REQUEST TO FRIEND
    public static void sendFriendRequest(String friendId){
        Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("message", "invite friends");
        params.putString("title", "Send a Request");
        params.putString("message", "Test Task");
        params.putString("to", friendId); 
        facebook.dialog(_activity, "apprequests", params, new DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                Constant.showAlertDialog("", "Friend request sent.", _activity.getParent(), false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {}
        });

    }
```

Please suggest the solution how can I send app request to my facebook friend sucessfully.

Comment: App requests go to the Requests link inside App Center, is that where you're looking?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is absolutely fine.What I assume is, you have not set the required fields in the `Facebook` app console.see the Following image.Those are the required fields in order to send app request.[image]

**Package Name:** Insert the package name of your app so that user will be redirected to your app in the `Google Play` if the app is loaded in the market.

**Class Name:** It is the launcher Activity name of your App.

**Key Hashes:** It is the unique identifier SHA1 key that you have to generate.

**Facebook Login, Deep Linking:** both need to be enabled.

Comment: Thanks for replying but I have done this in a different way.
I have set urls canvas url and secure canvas url in app on facebook option and it's done.